# Determine the exact datatype of ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Do we have any api or function which can be used to find the exact datatype while importing? I am implementing a feature in my application for importing data from external data source. For that i was using sqlbindcol() but it does not give the exact dataype. It returns a SMALL INT which is not the exact match.

Answer (score 0):

To find the datatype of Oracle columns:

```
select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'MYTABLENAME';
```